# d3 mapping with zoom but strange pan limit beavure

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, mapping, zooming

I'm making a series a maps of Italy and I started with this template: http://techslides.com/responsive-d3-map-with-zoom-and-pan-limits/

The problem is that when a zoom into my map http://www.danielepennati.com/prove/mapping/ita_pop_den.html the pan is limited and I can zoom in the eastern part of the map

the projection is defined like this:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
      .scale(3300)
      .center([12, 42])
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

and the zoom:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 13])
      .on("zoom", move);
function move() {

    var t = d3.event.translate;
    var s = d3.event.scale;  
    var h = height / 3;

    t[0] = Math.min(width / 2 * (s - 1), Math.max(width / 2 * (1 - s), t[0]));
    t[1] = Math.min(height / 2 * (s - 1) + h * s, Math.max(height / 2 * (1 - s) - h * s, t[1]));

    zoom.translate(t);
    g.style("stroke-width", 1 / s).attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");
  }
```

Could you help me?
this is my first attempt with d3 mapping :-)
thanks
daniele

Comment: The key is in your setting `t[0]` and `t[1]`. You're limiting the values there using `Math.min` and `Math.max`. To change the limits, adjust the values there.

Comment: In addition to Lars's comment there's a small typo in ` g.style("stroke-width", 1 / s).attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");` you're missing a comma between translate and scale, as in ` g.style("stroke-width", 1 / s).attr("transform", "translate(" + t + "),scale(" + s + ")");`

Comment: Thanks both for the comments. I tried to change the math limiting the panning, but I haven't figured out how to fix it. Anyway I commented the t[0] and t[1] lines and now the map has no pan limit and work quite well. If you have any advice on how to fix the pan limit math I'll really appreciate. Thnaks again